# What are the common "backing field" naming schemes in .net?

Tags: .net, properties, field, naming-conventions

When doing a backing field for a property what are the common naming schemes?

Edit: make question specific to .net

Comment: what programming language are you working in?

Comment: Well i am working with .net but imagine this is a multi language problem

Comment: most languages don't support properties. The few languages I know off the top of my head that do support them include C#, python, D and ruby. Languages that don't support them include perl, C, C++, *TRAN, Cobol, ad infinitum. Backing field names are going to vary from language to language as far as what qualify as reserved names, or even general convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conventions differ from language to language.

In Delphi, there's a very strong convention that internal member variables are prefixed with "F" for "Field".

```
public 
    property Name : string read FName write FName;

private
    FName : string;
```

In C++, there's a similar convention specifying underscore `_` as the prefix.

Lots of C# developers use `_` or `m_` for members, though it's my understanding that Microsoft officially discourages this.

**Update**: Corrected an embarrasing mistake - the Delphi convention is `F` for *field*, not `m` for `Member`.

Answer (score 6):

I usually use the property name itself, camel-cased and prefixed with an underscore:

```
private int _someProperty;
public int SomeProperty
{
    get { return _someProperty; }
    set { _someProperty = value; }
}
```

If you're using C# and the property is just a simple field accessor then you can use auto-implemented properties and the naming problem just disappears:

```
public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I have

- Lower case first character.

  `Property = GivenNames`

  `Field = givenNames`
- Under score first character.

  `Property = GivenNames`

  `Field = _GivenNames`